# How convert Bundle to WorkManager Data

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-intentservice, android-bundle, android-workmanager

I try to get rid of `IntentService` when handle `GCM` as described [here.](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-24-sending-receiving-android-push-notifications-with-gcm-google-cloud-messaging/) Because of Android O background limitation. But i can't pass [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) extras with push info as parameter to `WorkManager` from `BroadcastReceiver`. Is there any way to put Bundle into `WorkManager` [Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Data)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve this problem in a simple way. I noticed, that the whole parameters of Bundle are Strings, so i just put them into Data in broadcastReceiver and convert back in Worker.

```
class GcmWorker : Worker() {
    companion object {
        fun createWork(extras: Bundle): OneTimeWorkRequest {
            val dataBuilder = Data.Builder()
            extras.keySet().forEach {
                dataBuilder.putString(it, extras.getString(it))
            }

            return OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(GcmWorker::class.java)
                    .setInputData(dataBuilder.build())
                    .build()
        }
    }

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val extras = Bundle()
        for (key in inputData.keyValueMap.keys) {
            extras.putString(key, value)
        }
        // ...
        return WorkResult.FAILURE
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I use that with a pending intent?